# How to update an input with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I click on the button Language, I receive an overview of the languages.

```
$(".Language").on("click", overviewLanguage);

function overViewLanguage() {

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/Language/getAll', function (languages) {
        var htmlString = "<ul>";
        languages.forEach(function (language) {
            htmlString += "<li languageId=" + language.language_id + "><p>" + language.nameLanguage + "</p></li>" + "<br>";
        });
        htmlString += "</ul>";

        $(".middleScreen").html(htmlString);

        $(".middleScreen li").on("click", detailLanguage);
    });
}
```

When I click on a language, I receive the details.

```
function detailLanguage() {

    var languageId = $(this).attr("languageId");

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/Language/getById?Language_id=' + languageId, 
function (data) {

        $("#txtLanguageId").val(data.language_id);
        $("#txtLanguage").val(data.nameLanguage);
    });
}
```

When I change the name of the language and then I click on the update button, nothing happens. Can anyone help me please?

```
$("#updateLanguage").on("click", updateLanguage);

function updateLanguage() {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/Language/update',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonLanguage()),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, status) {
            overViewLanguage();
        },
        error: function (status) {
        }
    });
}


function jsonLanguage() {
    var newLanguage = {
        Language_id: $("#txtLanguageId").val(),
        nameLanguage: $("#txtLanguage").val()
    };
    return newLanguage;
}
```

Comment: don't you need to move your overview language function outside of language on click event then both that event and the success of your post method can call it?

Comment: @BryanDellinger, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: txtLanguageId,txtLanguage What are?

Comment: @hamedhossani, these are inputs.

Comment: Remove ```JSON.stringify``` from ```updateLanguage``` and Try?

Comment: @hamedhossani, no it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

please use this.

```
function updateLanguage() {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/Language/update',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {Language_id : $("#txtLanguageId").val(),
               nameLanguage:$("#txtLanguage").val()},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, status) {
            overViewLanguage();
        },
        error: function (status) {
        }
    });
}
```

and be aware in server side get parameter with same name
`$this->input->post('Language_id'`).
for example in `PHP`